# how to get the record of default value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on the database design of a multilingual website. I want to use the following popular method:

```
postid  |   post_title  |  lang
------------------------------
1       |  title1        |  en
1       |  title2        |  fr
2       |  title3        |  en
```

When i change the language i run a query to get the post like

```
select post_title from post where lang = "en" group by postid

postid  |   post_title  |  lang
------------------------------
1       |  title1        |  en
2       |  title3        |  en


select post_title from post where lang = "fr" group by postid

postid  |   post_title  |  lang
------------------------------
1       |  title2        |  fr
```

The problem is if i want a query which give me the result like

```
 postid  |   post_title  |  lang
------------------------------
1       |  title2        |  fr
2       |  title3        |  en
```

means if i don't get the post of **fr** language post then i should get default **en** language post.

Comment: Sorry, realized I wrote some crap, deleted it.

Comment: because postid = 2 is not in fr language so i want defualt en language of post.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return rows where `lang` = `"fr"` or rows where `lang` = `"en"` if no record has been found in `"fr"` for the corresponding `postid`.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM post AS a
WHERE
    a.lang = "fr"
    OR (
        a.lang = "en"
        AND (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM post AS b
            WHERE
                b.lang = "fr"
            AND b.postid = a.postid
        ) = 0
    )
GROUP BY a.postid
```

This attempt works but I can't tell if this is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: this query provide me only the result of en language. The en language post should be selected only when i dont have fr language of post.But i have one fr and one en language of post.

Comment: Hi @HarshwardhanSharma, I created a table exactly as yours and tested my query and it works. Maybe you didn't copied it correctly ?

Comment: you are right. It worked for me but is it the write way? means what else is the way i can achieve it.

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma I can't tell, I'm not an SQL expert. You can still accept my answer if you think it solved your issue. If a better answer comes you'll set it to the accepted one.